# Is it possible to give discount to customer who have previous purchase in magento2 cart rule?

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I am trying to add a cart price rule in magento2 for giving 10% discount to item when that customer have previous purchase.

But in condition section there is no customer related options for creating rule.

Is it possible to create this rule in magento? or can i full fill this using any extension?

Answer (score 0):

In **Magento 2 CE** - There is no option to give customer specific discount

But yes there are some third party extension available for that , here is the link  - https://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html

In **Magento 2 EE** - There is one featured called Customer Segmentation , You can create customer specific segment and 
give condition for the discount which you would like to apply for that customer.